# $sum aggrigate with distint condition MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

**Collection of Player Stats**

```json
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("612d07a8a8a6a71ee90dadc3"), 
    "player" : ObjectId("612895db68507d470af61326"), 
    "team" : ObjectId("611cd49e9be5e530de899065"), 
    "role" : "IGL", 
    "steamid" : "STEAM_1:1:239330230", 
    "kills" : NumberInt(19), 
    "deaths" : NumberInt(17), 
    "assists" : NumberInt(3), 
    "match" : ObjectId("6128d5ffa2988ca4cb03a958"), 
    "game" : ObjectId("606701ed58d20c0e47d95fee"), 
    "league" : ObjectId("60f139faf2dfa914ad5682b6"), 
    "map" : "de_dust2", 
    "win" : 1.0
}
```

I want the total wins per map of a team based on distinct matches, only $sum win for a unique match.

**Query**

```js
let teamWinsOnMap = await PlayerStats.aggregate()
        .group({ _id: {team: "$team", map: "$map"}, 
      match: { $addToSet: '$match' },
      team: { $first: '$team' },
      map: { $first: "$map" },
      win: { $sum: '$win' }
    })
```

**Result**

```js
[
  {
    _id: { team: 611cd49e9be5e530de899065, map: 'de_inferno' },
    match: [ 612cc791b0c36af46dbd0c01, 612cc791b0c36af46dbd0c08 ],
    team: 611cd49e9be5e530de899065,
    map: 'de_inferno',
    win: 0
  },
  {
    _id: { team: 611cd49e9be5e530de899065, map: 'de_dust2' },
    match: [ 6128d5ffa2988ca4cb03a958 ],
    team: 611cd49e9be5e530de899065,
    map: 'de_dust2',
    win: 2
  }
]
```

**PROBLEM**
The Team is having 2 wins while playing just one match, because we have stats of two player for that match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that whilst you are returning unique matches from addToSet, you aren't actually grouping by them and it's just counting the wins from all the documents that are inside that group stage.

If you were to perform two separate groups it should work. The first will get all unique matches by team on a certain map, take the first win count from that group as they should all be the same. Then group again and apply the sum it will return the correct value.

```
Group
{
  _id: {
    match:"$match", team:"$team", map:"$map"
  },
  team:{$first:"$team"},
  map:{$first:"$map"},
  match:{$first:"$match"},
  win:{$first:"$win"}
}
```

And then by

```
Group
{
  _id: {
    team:"$team", map:"$map"
  },
  team:{$first:"$team"},
  map:{$first:"$map"},
  matches:{$addToSet:"$match"},
  win:{$sum:"$win"}
}
```